# Basic tic tac toe game not recognising win

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create a basic tic tac toe game. When I first created this the user would click on an image box, that image box would then change to the respective players counter. The image location would be stored in a variable and applied similar to this:

```
string Cross = "ProjectFile/etc/..";
Image1.ImageLocation = Cross;
```

In order to see if the player had completed a row of three I'd have 2 if statements like so, one for a cross and one for a circle:

```
if(image1.ImageLocation == Cross && Image2.ImageLocation == Cross && Image3.ImageLocation == Cross)
{
  //Display message box, you've won etc.
}
```

This worked fine however I realized that when publishing this file the image location would not exist on a different computer. So I put the images into a resource file. and used them like so:

```
Position1.Image = Properties.Resources.Cross;
```

this works fine when loading the images onto the game however when it comes to checking whether or not the player has won, it does not recognise a complete row, I am currently using an if statement like this:

```
if ((Position1.Image == Properties.Resources.Cross && Position2.Image == Properties.Resources.Cross && Position3.Image == Properties.Resources.Cross) || //etc.
```

how can I see if the the image that the picture box is using is the same as the image in the resources file?

Comment: Firstly, I'd stop checking for wins by checking the images and instead have a 2D array that holds the state of each box and check that instead. Then your images should be "bound" to the corresponding element in your array.

Comment: @MattBurland Okay, arrays have always seemed rather daunting to me for some reason, but I'll try to implement it, cheers.

Comment: Also look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127898/2-in-a-row-c-sharp-program-game/13128090#13128090). Tic-Tac-Toe is just a simplified version of 4 in a row, so some of the same logic applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would re-architect the game logic to not check the images, but instead create a 3x3 matrix of `int` values.  Then assign blank to be 0, X to be 1, and O to be 2. (UPDATED:  Now `enum` values)

On your image box `OnClick` event, take the specific image box, figure out its index into the matrix, and set the value to the appropriate value.  Then check to see if there is a winner.

Winning logic could me something like this: (Updated to have `enum` instead of int. Thanks Matt Burland!)

```
enum TicTacToeSquare
{
    Blank,
    X,
    O
}

...

private TicTacToeSquare[][] _board;

...

public bool IsWinner(TicTacToeSquare player)
{
    if(player == TicTacToeSquare.Blank)
        return false;

    if(_board.Any(i => i.All(ii => ii == player)))
        return true;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if(_board.All(item => item[i] == player))
            return true;
    }

    if(_board[0][0] == _board[1][1] && _board[1][1] == _board[2][2])
        return true;

    if(_board[0][2] == _board[1][1] && _board[1][1] == _board[2][0])
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

That was just a quick stab, I'd check it before you finalize it.

Comment: For bonus points, use an enum of `CellState` with `Blank`, `X` and `O` as possible values and have an array of `CellState` instead of `int`. That way you don't have to remember if `1` means `X` or `O` or blank. Also you don't have the problem where `0` means blank and not `O`.

Comment: @JBurnham no prob :) I was trying to think of one Linq query that would determine a winning set, but it hasn't come to me yet.  If I figure it out, I'll post back

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare references.  `Position1.Image` is a reference to that image, `Properties.Resources.Cross` is a different reference, possibly to the same image, but also possibly not.  I would create a new object that contains some sort of image ID or image name and rather than trying to compare the images directly, compare the names or IDs.  Alternatively, you can override both the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods to allow you to directly compare 2 image objects but that is more work than what I prefer to do when it comes OOP.