# XO game not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the JS Code:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var step = 1;
        var e;
        function move(a){
            if (step % 2 == 0)
                e = "O";
            else
                e = "X";
            document.getElementById(a).innerHTML = e;
            step++;
            alert(document.getElementById(a).value);
        }
    </script>
```

and the HTML:

```
        <table border="1" align="center">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3">X O Game</th>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td id="td1" height="50" width="50" onclick="move('td1');"></td>
                <td id="td2" height="50" width="50" onclick="move('td2');"></td>
                <td id="td3" height="50" width="50" onclick="move('td3');"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td id="td4" height="50" width="50" onclick="move('td4');"></td>
                <td id="td5" height="50" width="50" onclick="move('td5');"></td>
                <td id="td6" height="50" width="50" onclick="move('td6');"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td id="td7" height="50" width="50" onclick="move('td7');"></td>
                <td id="td8" height="50" width="50" onclick="move('td8');"></td>
                <td id="td9" height="50" width="50" onclick="move('td9');"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

its seems the td's are undefined and why is that?.. can any one help me?
if you press on used td its oweride it.

Comment: I don't think `.value` works on a td

Comment: He's right, .value doesn't work on a td. You have to use `alert(document.getElementById(a).innerHTML)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `.value` on a TD. Use `innerHTML`. Check to see that it's empty before setting it to a new value. For example:

```
   function move(a) {
       var elem = document.getElementById(a);
       if (!a.innerHTML) {
           if (step % 2 == 0) e = "O";
           else e = "X";

           elem.innerHTML = e;
           step++;
       }
   }
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/wo2t5Lrn/

Now if you click on an already used cell, it will ignore it. You could add an `else` clause if you want to, for example, display an error message rather than use ignore the user.

I assume you next step will be to figure out who won. Check this out: [2 in a row c# program game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127898/2-in-a-row-c-sharp-program-game/13128090#13128090) although it's C# (but I only answered in pseudo-code anyway), the principle is the same. You only need to check if the current move is part of a win state by checking if it's part of a line of three.

EDIT: just for fun, I decided to try getting the thing to actually work:

http://jsfiddle.net/wo2t5Lrn/4/