# Connect 4 check diagonally

Tags: c#, .net

Hallo I can see this question been asked before. However I do not understand or can see how I can implment it myself. If its possible could you explain what you are doing and maybe add some kind of pseudo code so I can see the flow of the script.

I've done the vertical and horizontal lines like this and yes `PlayingBoard` is a 2d Array:

```
        private void HasWon(int xPlaced, int yPlaced) {
        //MessageBox.Show(xPlaced.ToString()+","+yPlaced.ToString());
        int[] Coords = new int[2];

        /// <summary>
        /// This part checks if we have a win on East or West
        /// </summary>
        Coords[0] = xPlaced;
        Coords[1] = yPlaced;
        while(Coords[0] != 0)
        {
            Coords[0] -= 1;
            if (PlayingBoard[Coords[0], Coords[1]] == playerValue)
            {
                foundInRow += 1;
            }
            else { break; }
        }

        Coords[0] = xPlaced;
        Coords[1] = yPlaced;
        while (Coords[0] < 6)
        {
            Coords[0] += 1;
            if (PlayingBoard[Coords[0], Coords[1]] == playerValue)
            {
                foundInRow += 1;
            }
            else { break; }
        }
        if (foundInRow > 2) { MessageBox.Show("You won."); Won = true; }
        else { foundInRow = 0; Won = false; }

        /// <summary>
        /// This part checks if we have a win on North or South
        /// </summary>
        Coords[0] = xPlaced;
        Coords[1] = yPlaced;
        while(Coords[1] != 0)
        {
            Coords[1] -= 1;
            if (PlayingBoard[Coords[0], Coords[1]] == playerValue)
            {
                foundInRow += 1;
            }
            else { break; }
        }

        Coords[0] = xPlaced;
        Coords[1] = yPlaced;
        while (Coords[1] < 6)
        {
            Coords[1] += 1;
            if (PlayingBoard[Coords[0], Coords[1]] == playerValue)
            {
                foundInRow += 1;
            }
            else { break; }
        }
        if (foundInRow > 2) { MessageBox.Show("You won."); Won = true; }
        else { foundInRow = 0; Won = false; }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Essentially you need to work out what element of the array is one up and one right (for example)

Comment: Coords[0] = x
Coords[1] = y
That is what is up and whats down.

And I have tried a lot of stuff um the flow I tried to do was:
`while(continue = true)
{
     if(Coords[0] > 0 && Coords[0] < 7 && Coords[1] < 6)
     {
          Coords[0] += 1;
          Coords[1] - = 1;
          if (PlayingBoard[Coords[0], Coords[1]] == playerValue)
            {
                foundInRow += 1;
            }
            else { break; }
     }
}`

Comment: See if any of this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127898/2-in-a-row-c-sharp-program-game/13128090#13128090

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a connect four solver which works using recursion.

It accepts a 2 dimensional array b which represents the board. each element in the array can be populated with an int where 0 represents an empty space 1 player one, 2 player two etc

the Checkboard method returns an int where -1 represents no winner and positive integers represent the winning players number

the method works by iterating through each square in the array from 0,0 and checking the three possible directions, left, diagonal and down for a further 3 adjacent elements containing the same number. if a row of 4 is found the method returns the number in the square it was checking at the time.

```
    public class Connect4Solver
    {
        public int Checkboard(int[,] b)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < b.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < b.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    for (int d = 0; d < 3; d++)
                    {
                        int p = b[x, y];
                        if (p != 0)
                        {
                            if (countDir(0, b, x, y, d, p) >= 3)
                            {
                                //win for p
                                return p;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return -1;
        }

        protected int countDir(int depth, int[,] b, int x, int y, int dir, int p)
        {
            int x2;
            int y2;
            if (getposdir(b, x, y, dir, out x2, out y2) == p)
            {
                //good
                depth++;
                return countDir(depth, b, x2, y2, dir, p);
            }
            else
            {
                return depth;
            }
        }

        protected int getposdir(int[,] b, int x, int y, int dir, out int x2, out int y2)
        {

            if (dir == 0)
            {
                x2 = x + 1;
                y2 = y;
            }
            else if (dir == 1)
            {
                x2 = x + 1;
                y2 = y + 1;
            }
            else if (dir == 2)
            {
                x2 = x;
                y2 = y + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("unknown");
            }
            return getpos(b, x2, y2);
        }

        protected int getpos(int[,] b, int x, int y)
        {
            if (b.GetLength(0) <= x)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            if (b.GetLength(1) <= y)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            return b[x, y];
        }

    }
```

> note: I forgot to check 'down and right' assuming it would like 'down'
>   and 'left' not be required. I leave this as an exercise for the reader
>   to add

Comment: now to condense it down to a single linq statement...

Comment: This is a bit overwhielming may exceed my knowledge. Can you maybe explain it a bit and how I should call the fuction and use them. My whole code looks like this:
[link](http://pastebin.com/vawNQKgX)

Also my layout looks like this.
http://i61.tinypic.com/2luux7a.png

The white buttons are called btyx.
And the grey ones are called "row1-row7"

Comment: updated. this is like your has won function but with less swearing. call it by instantiating the object and then call the Checkboard() method passing in your PlayingBoard object if a player has 4 in a row it will return the player number. if not it will return -1

Comment: hah, ive just realized there is in fact a fourth direction! diagonaly down and right, which should also be checked. I leave it as an exercise of the reader

Comment: Diagonaly down right I tried to add...But I got array out of index. I only changed a few lines:
`for (int d = 0; d < 4; d++)`
In the Checkboard function and under `getposdir` I added:
`else if (dir == 3)
            {
                x2 = x - 1;
                y2 = y + 1;
            }`

I get array out of bound when I add a tile at the 0,0

Comment: Seems to work I gotta try tomorrow I added if Y or X is less than 0 then return -1;

Comment: your change looks correct!