# Can't make a win checker in c# connect four game using windows forms

Tags: c#

This is my code so far,im trying to make a c# connect four game but i cant seem to get the win checker to work! I'd like for my game to be able to check for four in a row, horizontally, vertically and diagonally and show a message telling you the winner. I have checked and everything else works as it should.

```
namespace ConnectFour
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
     Button[] gameButtons = new Button[42]; //array of buttons for markers(red and blue)
     bool blue = true; //blue is set to true if the next marker is to be a blue

   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    this.Text = "Connect 4";
    this.BackColor = Color.BlanchedAlmond;
    this.Width = 500;
    this.Height = 500;

    for (int i = 0; i < gameButtons.Length; i++)
    {
        int index = i;
        this.gameButtons[i] = new Button();
        int x = 50 + (i % 7) * 50;
        int y = 50 + (i / 7) * 50;

        this.gameButtons[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
        this.gameButtons[i].Name = "btn" + (index + 1);
        this.gameButtons[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
        this.gameButtons[i].TabIndex = i;
        //this.gameButtons[i].Text = Convert.ToString(index);
        this.gameButtons[i].UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.gameButtons[i].Visible = true;

        gameButtons[i].Click += (sender1, ex) => this.buttonHasBeenPressed(sender1, index);
        this.Controls.Add(gameButtons[i]);
    }
  }
  private void buttonHasBeenPressed(object sender, int i)
  {
    if (((Button)sender).BackColor == Color.BlanchedAlmond)
    {
        if (blue == true)
        {
            ((Button)sender).BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            ((Button)sender).BackColor = Color.Blue;
        }
        blue = !blue;
    }
  }
private void fourInARow(int a, int b, int c,int d)
{
    if (gameButtons[a].BackColor == gameButtons[b].BackColor && gameButtons[a].BackColor == gameButtons[c].BackColor && gameButtons[a].BackColor==gameButtons[d].BackColor)
    {
        if (gameButtons[a].BackColor == Color.Blue)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("the winner is player 1");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("the winner is player 2");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [ask]. You need to describe the desired behaviour and what happens instead. Or if you get any compiler errors or exceptions then you need to show them, too. A question like: "hey my game doesn't work, please fix it" is too broad for and off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: And what exactly can't you get to work? You can't expect us to look at a dump of code and fix it for you. Please tell us what you put in and what you expect as output

Comment: See if this helps at all: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13128090/1250301

Comment: First, imagine an "endless" board in each direction. You want to know if some given x/y coordinate is the *start* of four connected cells with the same color. How many directions can you go? Straight up, down, left and right and also up-right, up-left, down-right and down-left. Eight in total. Now imagine a fixed sized board, where you start at bottom left for example. From there, you have only three directions to check (up, right and up-right). Did you find four connected cells? If yes, great, someone won. If not, go one cell to the right and check the same three directions.

Comment: Continue doing that. Don't bother looking "back" (i.e. to the left), because if there were four connected cells to the left, you would've already found them. If you're close to the right border (distance < 4) you can obviously skip right and up-right checks. If you didn't find anything on the bottom row, go one row up and start on the far left again. And again, "backwards" and "downwards" checks are unnecessary. Continue and if you're near the top row (distance < 4 again), you can skip up and up-right checks.

Comment: @Corak: Brute force searching the whole board is a waste of time. Since you know that the only way to get to a win state is by the action of one player making a move, the only search you need to do is starting with the last space played search up, up-right, right,...etc to see if *that* space is part of a line of 4.

Comment: @MattBurland - Agreed. But the last action could be somewhere in the middle of four connected cells. So the algorithm might be a bit more complicated to get right. Also, the absolute time difference for a board with 42 cells is probably negligible. But yes, absolutely, only the eight directions (at most) around the last action *need* to checked.

Comment: @Corak: It really isn't that much more complicated, you count the cells to the left that match (until you find one that is the opposite color), then if that's less than the number to win (4), you add the number matching to the right. If that's still less than 4 you check up/down, then up-left/down-right then up-right/down-left (obviously quitting as soon as one of them gives you 4 matches).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use Index?

```
int index = I;
```

will stay at "0" - because its an initializer and only called once in for-loop. 
But it makes no sense for me at all to have an index var.

Comment: Used it to number the buttons in my grid.